# Can anyone suggest a way to whitelist only our company domain?

Tags: whitelist

Okay so,

I work IT for a warehouse operation. Our warehouse management system is web based, meaning we need to use IE Firefox and Chrome to access it.

This comes with the unfortunate side effect of allowing associates access to internet capable PCs. We recently, as a result, were subject to a malware affliction because somebody was taking advantage of this and was accessing unauthorized sites.

In short, I need some way to whitelist only the domain to our WMS that works on all three browsers.

We have a method that works only for IE but there are several stations that require use of Chrome and Firefox too.

Can anyone offer suggestions? I'm not afraid of repeating an action on every individual PC if I have to, I just need to ensure they can access only our domain.

We run on Dell Optiplex 4020's and 4010's on Windows 7.

For added challenge, access does not go through a proxy server that I have access to. The highest form of control I have is local administrator on each PC.

Not a lot to work with I know but anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: Unless this website is on the internet, there is no reason to provide access to it, if the website is actually on the intranet.  The simplest solution is to use a proxy, you can configure a VPS as a proxy, and then configure the proxy to only allow access to websites you approve.  You can then configure the clients to use that proxy.  If you configure your systems so the proxy cannot be configured without Administrators rights, then the proxy cannot be unconfigured.

Comment: transparent proxy would work as well. don't leave anything to client configuration, that can be undone ... do it on network level at the router/gateway

Comment: Definitely look at gateway protections as the others have noted.